# android project with odatajclient library gives runtime error

Tags: android

I am developing android application using odatajclient library . App works fine if I build it through `maven android plugin` . But when I create android project and provide all the dependencies at runtime I am getting following class not found error

```
05-05 14:40:10.895: E/AndroidRuntime(14596): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by using apache olingo and the following sample:

https://github.com/Tirasa/olingoClientOnAndroidSample

When you initially run maven, it produces single jar for android client, which works perfectly fine at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Eclipse (Juno or above) : Right Click->properties->Build path->order export
Here select all the libraries. It will not be sufficient to just add the libraries through libraries.